# How to re-initialize source and layer after changing map style using react map gl library

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I am trying to change map view from streets to satellite view using react map gl library components but getting console errors of compiler not able to find source for corresponding layers. I have used by default Source and layer component of this library which works fine on initial page load but doesn't seems to work on changing map style. Moreover the layers are displayed fine on the map even after compiler generating console errors for same.

Can someone help me to diagnose the reason behind it and resolve it out completely.

[image: Source Code]

[image: Console Errors]

[image: Another console error]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution for it after a research. There is a prop present in ReactMapGL component of react map gl library named **preventStyleDiffing** which if set to true would prevent internal library code to find the difference in style properties whenever we try to switch map style from one option to another. Following this approach cleared the compiler generated issues for me.

Comment: now it's called styleDiffing instead, but it still doesn't work for me. would love to see how you managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is that if you're keeping state for the style, you need to pass it as the key of the Map. The best practice here would be using reuseMaps and also keep track of the style in the id prop:

```
<Map
  key={mapStyle}
  reuseMaps
  id={`${MapId}-${mapStyle}`}
>
  {/* Your sources and layers here */}
</Map>
```